How do I achieve the ping-ponging technique in HLSL compute shaders?
I am doing a fluid simulation, and implementing such simulation with the CPU is very slow, especially when the simulation grid size gets bigger or is a 3d grid. So I used shaders to get the calculation done in parallel with the GPU, and here I got into a problem. One of the steps of a grid fluid simulation requires solving a linear equation, which I am achieving with the jacobi method. Implementing this method on the CPU is fairly simple, but with the GPU working in parallel, I have to keep two copies of the buffer holding the resulting data, and at each iteration flip between the two so one is being read from and the other stored into. This technique is called ping ponging, and the problem is that I couldn't get my head around how to implement it as I am still new to shaders. Here is my current solution which I guess is clearly wrong. Any help how I can achieve the ping pong technique in here?
#pragma kernel Solve

RWStructuredBuffer<float3> Solution;
RWStructuredBuffer<float3> X;
StructuredBuffer<float3> X0;
float A;
float C;
int Iterations;
int N;

int index(int x, int y, int z) {
    return (x) + (y) * (N);
}

[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void Solve(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID) {
    int z = id.z;
    if (id.x >= N || id.y >= N || z >= N)
        return;

    float cRecip = 1.0f / C;

    for (int iter = 0; iter < Iterations; ++iter) {
        float3 q0C = X0[index(id.x, id.y, z)];
        float3 qRight = float3(0, 0, 0);
        float3 qLeft = float3(0, 0, 0);
        float3 qTop = float3(0, 0, 0);
        float3 qBottom = float3(0, 0, 0);

        if (id.x + 1 < N)
            qRight = X[index(id.x + 1, id.y, z)];
        if (id.x > 0)
            qLeft = X[index(id.x - 1, id.y, z)];
        if (id.y + 1 < N)
            qTop = X[index(id.x, id.y + 1, z)];
        if (id.y > 0)
            qBottom = X[index(id.x, id.y - 1, z)];

        float3 newValue = (q0C + A * (qRight + qLeft + qTop + qBottom)) * cRecip;
        Solution[index(id.x, id.y, z)] = newValue;
        X[index(id.x, id.y, z)] = newValue;
    }
}


I tried to switch between the data in the C# script (I am using Unity) but that led to a bottleneck because of dispatching the shader #iterations times.

I think I've seen people declare RWStructuredBuffer<float3> variables. If this is indeed possible, you can declare two, initialize them with your uniform buffers, and swap the variables between iterations.

I think the problem here is that you are implementing ping-pong technique but then overwriting the X StructuredBuffer. For example, in one threadgroup that contains say, four float3 values (so 4 ids) it will do the operations for the first id, then change its X[index] value to the new Value, however for the next id, when you try and grab X[(index new id)-1] so the id from the previews index it will grab instead the new value you assigned to X[(index new id)-1], so its changing the value based on the next frame basically, and will do so for each id that you have on a workgroup.
What you need to do instead:
On the HLSL side, keep it simple, read from X and write to Solve.
On the C# side what you need to do, is set two buffers, initialized with same proportions. Now you need to keep a bool variable that keeps check of which one to "set" to the X and which to "set" to "Solve" since you are going to be flipping them each frame.
I think it would look something like this
//Set them depending on the bool flag
RenderTexture currentBuffer = usePingBuffer ? pingBuffer : pongBuffer;
RenderTexture nextBuffer = usePingBuffer ? pongBuffer : pingBuffer;
        

//Set currentbuffer to the input and nextBuffer to output
compute.SetTexture(kernelToggle, "X", currentBuffer);
compute.SetTexture(kernelToggle, "Solve", nextBuffer);

   



compute.Dispatch(kernelToggle, data.width / 8, data.height / 8, 1);


//Change the flag for next frame
usePingBuffer = !usePingBuffer;

Hope this helps!
